# Find all solution of the following equation : $3^{m}-2^{n}=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

problem :

Find all solution of the following equation :

> $$3^{m}-2^{n}=1$$

Where $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$

My try but not complete :

In first we see that $m=n=1$ is a solution

Also: $m=2,n=3$ a solution 
But I don't know if have another solution or no

Is this equation has many solution ?

Comment: $m=1,n=1$? But $m=n=0 \implies 3^m-2^n = 1-1 = 0$

Comment: Yes sir thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of Catalan's conjecture. The only solution is $m=2, n=3$

Comment: I see but how we prove that ? 2,3 are only a solution ?

Comment: Welcome! Would you mind giving a link/tutorial (instead of just a name)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture if you don't mind.